# Pretty printing with GDB failes to show container values

Tags: c++, python, stl, gdb, cython

I have Ubuntu 13.10 with GDB 7.6.1, I downloaded the STL_pretty_printers from http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/ and ran it according to the instructions.

When first I ran the gdb I got a python Traceback message that says:

> raise ValueError , "Cannot parse more than 2 nodes in a tuple tree."

After some tinkering with the code I found that all the raise ValueError lines should be changed to

> raise ValueError("Cannot parse more than 2 nodes in a tuple tree.")

after that I tried to run a small test program (populating a vector) and when I try to show the content of the vector I get

> Python Exception  iter() returned non-iterator of type '_iterator':

Answer (score -1):

I tried searching for the solution with no avail, for some reason python is telling me that the _iterator class is not upholding the "[python iterator protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)". after pulling some hair for actually no reason I decided to try and uphold the "[Cython Iterator Protocol](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/special_methods_table.html#iterators)".

And for some reason... It works!

So

If you ever get the same problem here is a github of the [stl_pretty_printers for Cython](https://github.com/Manicqin/gdb_printers__python)

I would still like to find the reason why this problem occurred, if anyone has an idea please reply here.